# Access Caddy server API from http

Tags: http-proxy, caddy

I'm running `Caddy` server on an EC2 instance.

Write now I'm able to write config JSON inside the config `vim app.json` and load it from the SSH terminal.

```
curl localhost:2019/load -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @app.json
```

Now I want to load the configuration from another server over `HTTP`. Thus I have added the `admin` configuration to the `app.json`

```
{
  "admin": {
    "disabled": false,
    "enforce_origin": false,
    "origins": ["localhost:2019","103.55.1.2:2019","54.190.1.2:2019"]
  },
  "apps": {
    "HTTP": {
      "servers": {
        "scanning": {
          "listen": [":443"],
          "routes": [{
            "handle": [{
              "handler": "file_server",
              "root": "/var/www/html/app-frontend"
            }],
            "match": [{
              "host": ["caddy.example.com"]
            }]
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where the IP address

- 103.55.1.2: My ISP IP address
- 54.190.1.2: The EC2 private IP address

I'm trying to get the config from the postman using the EC2 IP address but it does not work.

```
http://54.190.1.2:2019/config/
```

**How can I get the config and load config in Caddy over `HTTP`?**